# What does c mean in the following question on cardinality?

Tags: real-analysis, question-verification

I found a question in Modern Real Analysis by William P. Ziemer. The question can be found in Section 2.1 Question 1. It goes:
Use the fact that $\mathbb N =$ {$ n: n = 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$} $\cup$ {$ n: n = 2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$}  to prove $c \cdot c = c$.
**What could they be referring to by c?** I know it has something to do with cardinality because the question continues as follows: Consequently, $card(\mathbb R^n) = c$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Also, what is the dot operator supposed to mean? How is it defined?

Comment: First of all: it's $2k + 1$ for one of the sets. However, $c$ is indeed the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^n$. You may want to use the fact that the cardinality of the power set of natural numbers is equal to the cardinality of real numbers.

Comment: My mistake. I copied and pasted one part without making the appropriate correction. I'm still a bit confused however. Can you tell me what c is supposed to represent and what the dot operator means? Edit: I have made the correction.

Comment: $\mathfrak c$ is used as the power of the continuum, the cardinality of the reals.

Comment: @RossMillikan God, that feels so obvious. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the structure of the question, it seems likely that the dot is just the product operator, which in the case of cardinalities means that $c \cdot c = card(\mathbb{R}) \cdot card(\mathbb{R}) = card(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$, i.e. the product of two cardinalities is the cardinality of the Cartesian product of the sets.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.